# Resuming waiting asynchronous script by receiveMessage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, asynchronous, protractor

Client1 has an iframe inside a window.
Client2 sends postMessage() via asynchronous script to Client1, then Client1 does something (bypassing cross-domain-policy-restriction). So far it works perfectly.
Now Client1 shall postMessage() back to Client2, so that he (2) can end his waiting (because of async.script execution).

How to accomplish.

Code snippets:

**CLIENT 2**

```
var iframe;
    return browser.executeAsyncScript(function (done) {
        window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);
        iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("message", "*");
        ##### HERE COMES HOW TO END WAITING #####
    }).then(function () {

    });
```

**CLIENT 1**

```
script.function setup() {
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);
        }

script.function receiveMessage(event) {
            if (event.data !== "message")
                return;
            // done something
            event.source.postMessage("message", event.origin); ?????
            // sth. like this
        }
```

MANY thanks for any hints

Comment: Also add a `window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);` in C2 and call `done` and `removeEventListener`(to make it only use once) in that `receiveMessage` in C2.

Comment: Can you elaborate this a little bit more, please? Meanwhile I already added the eventListener in C2, but how and when to call done?

Comment: I just see that there's also an `receiveMessage`, is that the same with C1, or you haven't decide how it looks?

Comment: Right now it´s exactly as shown above. I just don´t get how the event.source.postMessage from C1 fires the reveice-function in C2 ... it seems to be a problem that the async.script still waits, so no other function can be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `receiveMessage` in Client2 is, but as `addEventListener` will execute all handler that matches, I just add another event, if `receiveMessage` is different from the one in `Client1`, and the `done` is  accessible to receiveMessage`, then you don't need the new event handler I just created.

```
var iframe;

// The done passed in is the function to decide when to end the waiting.
// When you call `done`, the promise return by `browser.executeAsyncScript` knows its resolved
// and it'll start to execute whats in the `.then`.
return browser.executeAsyncScript(function (done) {
  // Dunno what `receiveMessage` is, or whether `done` is accessible to it, 
  //so I just created another function.
  // If its separate from one in `Client1`, than put the codes in `endWaitHandler` here.
  window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);

  var endWaitHandler = function() {
    // When we receive the message, call done to resolve promise
    done();

    // Remove the endWaitHandler so it won't get register many times if
    // this function called multiple times.
    window.removeEventListener("message", endWaitHandler);
  };

  // Register before sending the message.
  window.addEventListener("message", endWaitHandler);

  iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("message", "*");
}).then(function () {

});
```

Comment: Putting the reveicing Message - function INSIDE async-script did the trick, thanks a lot!